# Fixing a directory conflict in subversion

Tags: svn

I have a working copy that I cannot check in due to a conflict.  How do I update to the latest revision but yet keep my local changes to the files in the server directory?

i.e. here is what I have on my system

```
bob@blaze:~/dev/store$ ls -l
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 5 bob bob 4096 2010-09-23 00:17 Library
drwxr-xr-x 2 bob bob 2010-09-30 12:22 linclient
drwxr-xr-x 3 bob bob 4096 2010-09-30 12:15 server
drwxr-xr-x 3 bob bob 4096 2010-09-29 15:19 test_client
drwxr-xr-x 3 bob bob 4096 2010-09-30 10:11 test_scripts
```

Now, there should be a directory called client, I actually moved it under windows to test_client so it's all up to date.  But for some reason I can't get client to update to
the real client.  The error I'm getting is this:

```
bob@blaze:~/dev/store$ svn commit
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Aborting commit: '/home/bob/dev/store/client' remains in conflict
```

Subversion is great, until it breaks.  There is no conflict as such, it's just that the .svn folder contains a file that indicates a conflict.  How do I fix it so I can update and get the client directory to be downloaded to my working copy as well?

Comment: What does `svn stat` say? And have you tried `svn resolved client`?

Comment: that works too, but resolved is depricated

Comment: svn resolved client worked.  Ascherer's answer didn't right off so I used your solution.

Comment: Would have accepted this as it worked, but since it's deprecated I'll accept archerer's answer when he fixes it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you should be able to run

```
svn resolve --accept=working /home/bob/dev/store/client
```

Comment: Wouldn't `svn resolve --accepted=theirs-full` be more to the point? Or am I misinterpreting the workings?

Comment: yeah, whichever one is better for the situation

Comment: The command line help says "svn resolve --accept=ARG [PATH...]" not accepted.

Comment: I will accept your answer when you correct the command line arguments which are wrong.

Answer (score 5):

To accept working copy :

svn resolve --accept=working /home/bob/dev/store/client

or to reject working copy :

svn revert /home/bob/dev/store/client